# Error when generating ZIP APP BUNDLE visual studio 2017 ios

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am trying to generate a zip bundle 
For publication in the apple store app more generate error , how to fix the error? How to include this key in my project, does this key have to be with the certificate?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QC9eJ.png)

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/#Requesting_a_Development_Certificate

Answer (score 0):

That error is given in response to no provisioning profiles setup on your MAC for AppStore or Ad-hoc distribution.

**Step 1: (cert install)**
You must first set up a cert on your machine (private key) that matches the public key in apple developer by using keychain.  You do this once per machine (apple limits number of certs unless enterprise).  NOTE: You can export that cert to a .p12 saving your private key (make sure you set a password) and using it on another MAC.  NOTE: You may also import a .p12 (private exchange cert) from another developer by double-clicking the cert and entering the password used to protect that cert.

**Step 2: (mobile provisioning install)**
Following the cert install you may now set up a dev or Ad-hoc/AppStore provisioning profile. In apple developer account make sure you bind the provisioning profile to your app/cert. Download the mobileprovisioning file from your apple developer account and install it on your MAC (double click to install) for builds.  You may work remotely in a PC (I do) but connect to your MAC for remote builds but the cert/provisioning must be done on the MAC for iOS builds. NOTE: Also make sure if you are using VS for MAC you sign out of your team account it can cause issues.  Or if using a team profile sign-in using that account created for you in VS for MAC.

Once you set these up you may create .ipa's for app store distribution.

[Apple Developer Cert Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html)

[Provisioning Profile Setup](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_to_the_app_store/profiles/)